# system of 2 linear differential equations with variable coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have a system of 2 linear diff equations but with a variable coefficients:

$$f''(x)+af'(x)+(1+x)g'(x)+bg(x)=0\\g''(x)+ag'(x)+(1-x)f'(x)-bf(x)=0$$

where $a,b$ are some positive constants. I have no idea how to solve this system (or even if it has an anayltic solution), I'll appreciate any help or some reference.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**: Let $f'(x)=h(x)$ and $g'(x)=k(x)$. The system of second order ODE can be reduced to an homogeneous system of first order with variable coefficients $z'(x)+A(x)z(x)=0$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
f'\\
g'\\
h'\\
k'
\end{pmatrix}+
\underbrace{
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 0 & a & 1+x\\
-b & 0 & 1-x & a\\
\end{pmatrix}}_{A(x)}\
\underbrace{
\begin{pmatrix}
f\\
g\\
h\\
k
\end{pmatrix}}_{z(x)}
=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Thus you can solve it by *Fundamental System of Solutions and Fundamental Matrix Method (Wronskian and Liouville's Formula)* or by  *Method of Variation of Constants (Lagrange Method)*